# Make fields editable when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, playframework

the user of my application should be able to change the email and the phone number by clicking in a button "Change", this is my code:

```
    <div class="field-group">
     ...............
     ....................
        <div class="field field-omschrijving">
          <label class="label">E-mailadres</label><div>@client.email</div>
         </div>
         <div class="field field-omschrijving field-last">
           <label class="label">Telefoonnummer</label><div>@client.phoneNumber</div>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Change" name="op">
       </div><!-- /.field-group -->
```

I've been looking for a solution but no success, any idea about how can I do it? Thanks!

Thanks so much for the fast response! But.. my mistake, what I wanted to say is that the fields should appear in a "normal way" and when the user clicks the button change it should change to an "editable way", right now the field email looks like this:![image]
I want it looks like this: [image: Pic. 2]

And after clicking in the "Change" button it has to look like the first image. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this code after click you can change your label to input, as in you pictures.
It will help you now, hope

```
 $( ".button_class" ).click(function() {
       $('.class_Of_label_email').replaceWith($('<input>' + $('.class_Of_label_email').innerHTML + '</input>'));
    });
```

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="first">Hello</div>
<div class="second">And</div>
<div class="third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
 $( ".container" ).click(function() {
$( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
}
```

Result is:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="inner first">Hello</div>
<h2>New heading</h2>
<div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Hope, it will help

Comment: Thanks! But when I click in the button nothing happens :(

Comment: Edited. Please, try again. Are you sure  you have .class_Of_label_email in the function the same as in your label??

Comment: Edited. Hope, it will help

Comment: Thanks, finally i did it this way: `ns.init = function(){
         $("#button-id").click(function() {
          $('#email').removeAttr("readonly");
        });

    };`

Comment: Great!!!) if the the questions is over, close it,please accepted one of the answers

Answer (score 2):

Give id to button and input fields for email and ph no.
On click of button, hide the lebel and show input fields.

```
<div class="field-group">
    <div class="field field-omschrijving">
        <label class="label">E-mailadres</label>
        <div id="divemail">@client.email</div>
        <div id="divemailinput"><input type="text" id="emailId"/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field field-omschrijving field-last">
        <label class="label">Telefoonnummer</label>
        <div id="divno">@client.phoneNumber</div>
        <div id="divnoinput"><input type="text" id="emailId"/></div>
    </div>
    <input id="btnchange" type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Change" name="op"/>
</div><!-- /.field-group -->
```

JS

```
$("#btnchange").click(function(){
    $("#divemail").hide();
    $("#divemailinput").hide();
    $("#divno").hide();
    $("#divnoinput").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first you need is put your 
@client.emailand @client.phoneNumber into inputs  and set them inactive.
Then, and after clicking change them to active by using javascript.

```
<input type="text" class="emailand_clas" readonly="readonly" >@client.emailand </input>
```

and using jquery:

```
$( ".button_class" ).click(function() {
    $('.emailand_clas').attr('readonly','')
});
```

Some thing like this

Comment: I think its 'attr' not 'atrr'

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question ,could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this JSFiddle or [my blog](http://binyit.blogspot.com/2014/07/jquery-enable-and-disable-textbox-make.html) for a great example.

http://jsfiddle.net/biniama/YDcFF/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>jQuery enable/disable button</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
     $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
        $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#submitBtn').val('Update');
     });
});
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
     /* Lets use a Google Web Font :) */
     @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint);
     /* Basic CSS for positioning etc */
     body {
          font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
          background-image: url('bg.jpg');
     }
     #frame {
          width: 700px;
          margin: auto;
          margin-top: 125px;
          border: solid 1px #CCC;
          /* SOME CSS3 DIV SHADOW */
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #CCC;
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #CCC;
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #CCC;
         /* CSS3 ROUNDED CORNERS */
         -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
         -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
         border-radius: 5px;
         background-color: #FFF;
     }
     #searchInput {
          height: 30px;
          line-height: 30px;
          padding: 3px;
          width: 300px;
     }
     #submitBtn {
          height: 40px;
          line-height: 40px;
          width: 120px;
          text-align: center;
     }
     #frame h1 {
          text-align: center;
     }
     #frame div {
          text-align: center;
          margin-bottom: 30px;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='frame'>    
        <div class='search'>
            <h1>jQuery Enable and Disable button</h1>

            <input type='text' name='searchQuery' id='searchInput' class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled'/> 
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' value='Edit'/>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now HTML5 is available so .
We can use attribute

> contenteditable

More help and details 
http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Answer (score -1):

```
<label class="label">E-mailadres</label>
<input type="text" class='email' value='@client.email' />

document.getElementsByClassName('form-submit').onclick=function(){

   document.getElementsByClassName('email').disabled=false;

};
```